# Create a PayPal client id to use with checkout.js for a third party business

Tags: paypal, paypal-sandbox, paypal-rest-sdk, django-paypal

I have developed some bespoke booking software which I host for 3rd parties.  Some of them require PayPal integration for their customer payments.

In my PayPal Developer account I have managed to create an app and sandbox account and have managed to get my test/dev site processing payments successfully.

I'm using **checkout.js** to create a PayPal button on the customer invoice page.

1. I assume I create an app for each of my clients that require PayPal access through my software?
2. How do I link the app to my clients business PayPal account?  I'm confused as to what I need to get them to do at their end.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that the third party must create their own PayPal Developer account and create an App within it, they then need to send you the App production client ID and primary email address of their PayPal business account.